# Set default direction (ordenation) in Catalog Search Result

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

Magento 2 uses default "asc" ordenation for category page and Layered Navigation. But in catalog search result page, the default direction is setted to "desc" and I've debugged the code, I've found the method `configureToolbar` in `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` these lines:

```
$dir = $this->getDefaultDirection();
if ($dir) {
   $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
}
```

I have debugged this, following the call stack until I reach the `DataObject.php`, where the `default_direction` property is setted, but I don't know where this value came from, so how can I change this default direction in my search result page? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic Magento issue.

One will go through colledge and then further self educate for a decade for all the programming principles, patterns and best practices and what not.

Eventually, one will debug and will get stuck with a question like this, myself included of course. Magento certainly does not make things easy for debug.

But, I think I got that code that sets the direction. I sadly present to you

```
Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result
```

and its method

```
public function setListOrders()
{
    $category = $this->catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory();
    /* @var $category \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category */
    $availableOrders = $category->getAvailableSortByOptions();
    unset($availableOrders['position']);
    $availableOrders['relevance'] = __('Relevance');

    $this->getListBlock()->setAvailableOrders(
        $availableOrders
    )->setDefaultDirection(
        'desc'
    )->setDefaultSortBy(
        'relevance'
    );

    return $this;
}
```

Now, you can perhaps change portions of it to

```
->setDefaultDirection(
    'hardcoded-direction'
)
```

and when you hit your debug point

```
$dir = $this->getDefaultDirection();
```

and in the `configureToolbar` method from `ListProduct` you will see that `$dir` value is `hardcoded-direction`.

You would expect from Magento to not hard code parameters for such an important eCommerce feature as the search is, but still, there it is.

Comment: Hi Marjan, thanks for answering, I've walked over and around this code and just couldn't see it haha. But I think I've noticed why magento default is "desc" here, when you use the "relevance" sort, the most relevant results goes to the end, tha's why it is setted as "desc", I'm trying to set to "asc" only if is NOT "relevance" sort, but your answer fits my question, thankyou.

Comment: You are welcome! :)